# failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, filestream, digital-ocean

I now upload my project to server in digital ocean,but I get this error in apache2 error log

> require_once(/var/www/html/example/v1../include/DbHandler.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory

The 2 line that occur error is this,is working well in localhost,but when go to server it having the error above

```
require_once '../include/DBHandler.php';
require_once '../include/PassHash.php';
```

My directory is as below,I have to required `DBhandler.php` which in `include` folder,and `index.php` is from `v1` folder(the place that `require_once` calling from).

```
-include
  -DBhandler.php
  -PassHash.php
-v1
  -index.php
```

Here is the error log I got

> [Fri May 19 12:33:19.621030 2017] [:error] [pid 5236] [client 115.133.247.14:575                                                                                                                     22] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/example/v1../include/                                                                                                                     DbHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/htm                                                                                                                     l/example/v1/index.php on line 9

**What I tried so far**

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/DBHandler.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/PassHash.php';`

And this,but none of this solve the problem

```
require_once __DIR__."/../include/DBHandler.php";
require_once __DIR__."/../include/PassHash.php";
```

Someone please help!Give me the a right direction,so I can proceed

Comment: yopu have caps in your include but your file name for dbhandler is lower case `/../include/DbHandler.php` doesn't match `-DBhandler.php`

Comment: sir,I change to DBhandler.php in my file of server,but it still having `500 internal error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your require :

```
require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';
```

Your filename:

```
DBhandler.php
```

The name is different.
Change your require to:

```
require_once '../include/DBHandler.php';
```

Comment: sir,I change to  `require_once '../include/DBHandler.php';` but the problem still the same.have another reason?

Answer (score 1):

May be your file name case: DBHandler intead of DbHandler

Comment: sir,I change to `require_once '../include/DBHandler.php`'; but the problem still the same.have another reason?

Answer (score -1):

Just Remove  the symbol  /  this on staring  of file path  your problem  will be sovled.

require_once(var/www/html/example/v1../include/DbHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: remove the `/` symbol wont solve the problem..So this is not the answer